# joomla htaccess rewrite url with hash

Tags: url, hash, url-rewriting

It's joomla and I need to rewrite this url:

```
http://www.example.com/component/dpcalendar/calendar.html#year=2017&month=4&day=28&view=month
```

to `http.example.com`

My problem is that when I rewrite this url, there is still `http.example.com/#year=2017&month=4&day=28&view=month`

How to remove it?

Comment: The bit after the hash in the URL is not sent to the server when requesting a page, so you can't use redirect rules like that. It's client-side only. Are you using some JavaScript calendar widget maybe? Can you edit the client-side file?

Comment: I thought so... well I probably could try to find javascript calendar, but I'll wait for www creator to fix this. I was trying to use rewrite just remporary :)